# What import do i need for inV() and hasID() in gremlin groovy (3.0.1-incubating)

Tags: groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to get a property value of an edge given source and dest vertex ids, and edge label.

in the gremlin terminal the following worked:

```
g.V("fromNodeId").outE("edgeLabel").where(inV().hasID("toNodeID")).values("edgeProp")
```

sadly, in groovy, the inV() and hasID() aren't recognized, and i can't find the correct import to get it to work.

here are the imports iv'e tried:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.*
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.*
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.function.*
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.*
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.filter.*
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Edge
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.EdgeTest;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph
```

i'll note that other queries s.a. the following work just fine:

```
String getPropValueByID(Long id, String prop){
    def result = []
    **g.V(id).values(prop).fill(result)**
    if(result.empty) return null

    return result.first()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the [TinkerPop3 documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#graph-traversal-steps)

> To reduce the verbosity of the expression, it is good to `import
>   static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.*`.
>   This way, instead of doing `__.inE()` for an anonymous traversal, it
>   is possible to simply write `inE()`. Be aware of language-specific
>   reserved keywords when using anonymous traversals. For example, in and
>   as are reserved keywords in Groovy, therefore you must use the verbose
>   syntax `__.in()` and `__.as()` to avoid collisions.

Comment: See also the [javadoc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/__.html) for __ (that's really the name of the class).